# Linking Textbox

Tags: android, spinner, textview

I got i drop down list containing 4 categories. On that same activity Those for categories haves contents 4-8 paragraphs each. Is it possible if I chose a category from the drop down list and it will jump to the corresponding category in the activity? Similar to the one in HTML

Comment: Are you setting the content to any view?
Could you please post some code

Comment: I havent done any coding yet because i dont know where to start.